# DNF displays error after package install on Fedora

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, dnf

I am having a strange exception each time a package is installed/upgraded with `dnf`!
However, the packages are well installed.
It seems like DNF is outputting some malformed JSON that causes thed `raw_decode()` function to raise an exception!

A screenshot of the backtrace:
[image: screenshot]

DNF log:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)

# cat /var/log/dnf.log

Jul 19 08:15:54 INFO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jul 19 08:15:54 INFO Total                                                                        114 kB/s | 7.5 MB     01:07     
Jul 19 08:15:54 INFO Delta RPMs reduced 32.4 MB of updates to 7.5 MB (76.1% saved)
Jul 19 08:15:54 INFO Running transaction check
Jul 19 08:16:05 INFO Transaction check succeeded.
Jul 19 08:16:05 INFO Running transaction test
Jul 19 08:16:34 INFO Transaction test succeeded.
Jul 19 08:16:34 DDEBUG timer: transaction test: 28600 ms
Jul 19 08:16:34 INFO Running transaction
Jul 19 08:17:01 DDEBUG RPM transaction start.
Jul 19 08:22:06 DDEBUG RPM transaction over.
Jul 19 08:22:16 DDEBUG timer: verify transaction: 9430 ms
Jul 19 08:22:16 DDEBUG timer: transaction: 342011 ms
Jul 19 08:22:16 INFO 
Installed:
  libcap-ng.i686 0.7.7-2.fc23                                                                                

Upgraded:
  GeoIP-GeoLite-data.noarch 2016.07-1.fc23               audit.x86_64 2.6.4-2.fc23                          
  audit-libs.i686 2.6.4-2.fc23                           audit-libs.x86_64 2.6.4-2.fc23                     
  audit-libs-python.x86_64 2.6.4-2.fc23                  gd.x86_64 2.1.1-8.fc23                             
  httpd.x86_64 2.4.23-3.fc23                             httpd-filesystem.noarch 2.4.23-3.fc23              
  httpd-tools.x86_64 2.4.23-3.fc23                       libburn.x86_64 1.4.4-1.fc23                        
  libisofs.x86_64 1.4.4-1.fc23                           libsmbclient.x86_64 2:4.3.11-1.fc23                
  libwbclient.x86_64 2:4.3.11-1.fc23                     openjpeg2.x86_64 2.1.1-1.fc23                      
  perl.x86_64 4:5.22.2-353.fc23                          perl-Math-BigInt.noarch 1.9997-353.fc23            
  perl-libs.x86_64 4:5.22.2-353.fc23                     perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.22.2-353.fc23               
  perl-open.noarch 1.10-353.fc23                         python.x86_64 2.7.11-7.fc23                        
  python-devel.x86_64 2.7.11-7.fc23                      python-libs.x86_64 2.7.11-7.fc23                   
  python3.x86_64 3.4.3-11.fc23                           python3-devel.x86_64 3.4.3-11.fc23                 
  python3-libs.x86_64 3.4.3-11.fc23                      samba.x86_64 2:4.3.11-1.fc23                       
  samba-client.x86_64 2:4.3.11-1.fc23                    samba-client-libs.x86_64 2:4.3.11-1.fc23           
  samba-common.noarch 2:4.3.11-1.fc23                    samba-common-libs.x86_64 2:4.3.11-1.fc23           
  samba-common-tools.x86_64 2:4.3.11-1.fc23              samba-libs.x86_64 2:4.3.11-1.fc23                  
  sudo.x86_64 1.8.17p1-1.fc23                            thunar-vcs-plugin.x86_64 0.1.5-1.fc23              
  xorg-x11-drv-openchrome.x86_64 0.5.0-1.fc23           

Jul 19 08:22:16 DEBUG Completion plugin: Generating completion cache...
Jul 19 08:22:18 INFO Complete!
Jul 19 08:22:18 DDEBUG Cleaning up.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/var/cache/dnf/tempfiles.json` was malformed. I fixed it (it could be deleted even).